# PHP open file and replace content

Tags: php, regex, fopen, file-get-contents, fwrite

```
<?php
$modcontent = file_get_contents('hello.xml');
preg_match("/<Content(.*?)>(.+?)<\/Content/s", $modcontent, $xmlmatches);
$search  = array('<![CDATA[',']]>');
$replace = array('','');
$thenewone = str_replace($search, $replace, $xmlmatches[2]);
fopen('hello.xml');
fwrite($thenewone);
fclose('hello.xml');
?>
```

Hi, starting from the code above (which doesn't work), can you make it so it will modify that hello.xml file to keep only the content between , like in the preg_match? The hello.xml is here http://www.google.com/ig/modules/hello.xml.
  Since my PHP and my English knowledge is quite low, I'll explain again in different words, hopefully you'll understand what I mean. I want a PHP script that can open the hello.xml file, read the content between the Content tags, write that content and replace everything else in the file and save the hello.xml file. Therefore, after all this operation, .xml should contain only *Hello, world!*.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a scary replacement! So easy to create invalid XML .. also, questions should explain what "doesn't work" means ..

Comment: Well, doesn't work means that my code doesn't do anything to that hello.xml file (maybe you can download the hello.xml file and test it, if not too much trouble). Also, I don't care about the invalid XML because, after the modification the script will do to the XML file, its content will no longer be xml ;)

Comment: Daniel, I suggest you better read about SimpleXML. It will help you a lot. It is always better to know PHP built in libraries rather than reinventing those simple(or not so) things every time.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but I think SimpleXML will only display a XML file, not do what I want; I need that xml file modified. Besides, I'm a little old to start learning PHP right now - only the faulty code above took me half day. I really don't have time, that's why I'm asking for help here :(

Answer (score 2):

Here try this using my fav, [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/modules/hello.xml');

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
@$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
//Get the node by tag then get the textContent/nodeValue
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Content')->item(0)->textContent;

//Hello, world! 
print_r($content);
//Write to file
file_put_contents('hello.txt',$content);
?>
```

Comment: Do I have to do something with this thread? Close, mark solved etc? I can't see any options.

Comment: Never mind, looks like some dude closed it anyway. Thanks again m8!